# Jquery Mobile - How to use ScrollView...What do I have to include?

Tags: jquery, mobile

This is my code:

```
        <div data-role="content" data-theme="b">
            <div data-scroll="y">
                <ul>
                    <li data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r" onclick="redirectPage(1);">All Day and All of the Night-Kinks</li>
                    <li data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r" onclick="redirectPage(2);">Sunshine of Your Love-Cream</li>

                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I have included all the files and still it wont work

Comment: Edit your question to include more information, don't put it in the comments. Primarily it's much more readable if it's in the question.

Comment: I meant that I included all the needed files .css and .js and still it won't work...

Comment: "Won't work" is too vague. Won't work how?

Comment: It wouldn't scroll... I meant I've done what the tutorial shows added data-scroll="y"...:-( still not working

Comment: What tutorial? We need more detail to answer your question.

Comment: I have this div above...I'm trying to make it scroll. I have added the data-scroll="y" since i want it to be vertical. I also included the needed files...I can't see what i'm missing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include the css file, and the jquery easing script.

Scripts must be included in this order:

- jquery
- jquery.mobile
- jquery.easing
- jquery.mobile.scrollview
- scrollview

The css file gives you the scroll bars, jquery.easing gives the smooth animation (an impressive project by itself), jquery.mobile.scrollview does the heavy lifting, scrollview scrapes the page and adds enough markup for the scrollview to take over.

It is 'Experimental' for a reason. The feature is not officially supported, however I have found very few problems with it on mobile devices.

It is also worth noting that implementing proper fixed toolbars is [expected to be released](http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2012/01/10/upcoming-releases-1-0-1-1-1-and-beyond/) in version 1.1, so it won't be needed to have the separate scrolling scripts to handle scrolling *only* the content. If you want other kinds of scrolling, you will still need the extra stuff.